# Product import causes duplicated SKU for simple products

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-import

We are importing new products into magento as a scheduled cron job. Inside the code we internally calls the FireGento\FastSimpleImport module to perform the import action. This module actually calls the default magento product import features.  Sometimes we can see there are a lot of simple products being created with Same SKU. Any Idea about this problem?